# invalid db driver codeigniter

Tags: mysql

I appear to have encountered an obscure codeigniter error, invalid db driver when I move from my remote server, to a local xampp server with default config! It's just a simple script using some mysql queries, the driver is mysqli, any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather inexplicably, a codeigniter upgrade from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1 solved this!